# AngularJs route not worrking properly for nested partial pages

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm new to AngularJS. I have done a piece of code where i have three partial pages. Am trying to load partial three from partial 2 when i click something. The problem is partial3 loads properly but angularjs binding not working properly.

here is my code.

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/view1',{
          templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html'
      })
      .when('/view2',{
          templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html'
      })
      .when('/view3',{
          templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
          controller : 'view3Ctrl'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);

myApp.controller('view3Ctrl',function($scope){

    $scope.name = "somename";
});

view2.html

<p>This is the partial for view 2.</p>
<p>
 this is view2
</p>
<p><a href="#/view3">Click here</a></p>

view3.html

<p>This is the partial for view 3.</p>
<p>
   this is view3
   <p> {{name1}}</p>
</p>
```

output:
This is the partial for view 3.

{{name1}}

instead of binding name it displays the {{name1}}

Comment: You have nothing in your scope called `name1`. And that all assumes that you actually created your controller correctly, which from the snippet you've shown doesn't appear to be the case either. If that's the case you have a couple errors with this code.

Comment: Matt, actually it was a typo, i have written as {{name}} in my view3.html. If am not wrong it looks like when i load view3.html the page is not considered  as angularjs app. Am i right??? any idea why that happens??

Comment: If that's the case then I would say it's because you didn't create your controller correctly. Let me write up an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you didn't create your controller correctly. You have a few options on how to do it and it will mainly depend on your coding style.

First, you can just chain it to the module call like below

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller();
```

Or you just need to call the module getter method instead of the setter. That would look like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []); //setter method
angular.module('MyApp').controller(); //getter method
```